# RabbitMQ - publish to Queue or Exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm a bit confused about RabbitMQ best practices regarding the use of *Queues* and *Exchanges*. Let's say I would like to deliver a `GenerateInvoice` message with some data for an invoice, and have multiple consumers processing the invoice data and generate a PDF. Each `GenerateInvoice` should be processed only by one consumer.

One approach is to declare an queue and publish the `GenerateInvoice` messages to this queue and let all consumers consume from this queue. That would distribute the message across the different consumers.

It's unclear to me, if the above is okay or best practice is delivering the messages to a *Exchange* instead of publishing them directly to a queue. Using an *Exchange* I have to ensure that an queue is declared after the producer has created the Exchange before it starts to publish messages. Otherwise no queue would receive the messages and the message would be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a queue, publishing GenerateInvoice messages to the queue and having multiple consumers for the queue would work in this scenario.

The messages published to the queue will not be lost and they stay on RMQ if there are no consumers. Only thing is to make sure queue is declared before messages are published.

Java Example:

```
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
```

Then, Publish can be done as:

```
channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
```

and consume can be done as:

```
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Five years later I got the same question.
But some research at this time brings me to another response:

> In RabbitMQ, a producer never sends a message directly to a queue.
> Instead, it uses an exchange as a routing mediator.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-rabbitmq-exchanges-queues-bindings